# Having conflict with Django URL and Angular Route

Tags: angularjs, django

I am currently working on a project using Django and Angular. I am trying to implement Django's Password-Reset app, which seems pretty easy to set up. I followed the instructions and I ran into a peculiar issue that is caused by Angular's routing. I am trying to link to a FormView using

```
<a href="{% url 'password_reset_recover' %}">Forgot password?</a>
```

But it seems that Angular's routing keeps picking up the literal translation of the link

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/%7B%%20url%20'password_reset_recover'%20%%7D
```

This of course causes a routing error to pop up.

Is there anyway I can link to this view without Angular interfering?

Comment: Did you resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the problem is that Django is not parsing your URL tag in the template. Might want to look into that rather than into Angular

Could you check the `a` tag in your Developer tools and see what it says? Chances are that it says exactly what the URL is pointing to.i.e. `/%7B%%20url%20'password_reset_recover'%20%%7D`

Have you added `password_reset_recover` in your root `urls.py`?

Comment: yeah I have password_reset_recover in my urls.py

Comment: Still no luck? Is it the same exact issue still?

Comment: yeah the charset is UTF-8 also, so that shouldn't be the issue. It's really annoying, it's the last thing I need to do to finish my web project.

Comment: I think I may repost the question with a different title, since I now know it has nothing to do with angular.